# How to kill a process in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Often times, some rogue processes gets in a busy spin mode using up 100% of the CPUs. I have a GCP Ubunutu instance with 4 CPU Cores and 32 Gigs of RAM. I still get into this situation of 100% CPU usage and I can't even SSH into the VM instance.

Does GCP provide a way of killing the offending process? Through gcloud SDK command or web console?

[image]

Comment: GCP does not provide you any tools like this. Furthermore, killing a process could cause data loss or/and unstable work of your service. Instead you should connect to the VM instance via SSH and investigate.

Comment: Do you have created a local user with a password on your VM?

Answer (score 0):

As Serhii Rohoza mentioned, GCP does not provide you any tool to kill proccess.
Instead, you can SSH your VM instance and figure out what process is eating away your CPU and stop it, by executing this commands:

1. Open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+t
2. Execute the command "top"
3. Note the process using the most CPU
4. If the process isn't a system process, kill it with "sudo pkill [processname]"
   where [processname] is the name of the process you want to kill.

If it is a system process, don't kill it, but try to Google the name of it and figure out what functionality it does in Ubuntu.